# Problem in cisco routing bgp routes

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp

We have an outbound route-map on an eBGP peer that adds some communities to certain prefixes. Is there any way to prove that this is actually happening from the sender side in classic IOS?

`show ip bgp neighbor x.x.x.x` `advertised-routes` does not show them

Even `debug ip bgp update out` doesn't seem to!

In gns3 I can make the same config and see that it works from my fake upstream side, but I need to be able to verify in the production router from the local side

Current configuration : 15583 bytes

```
version 15.1
no service pad
service tcp-keepalives-in
service tcp-keepalives-out
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service password-encryption
no service password-recovery
!
hostname Router1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no logging console
!
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
clock timezone GMT 0 0
!
no ipv6 cef
no ip source-route
no ip gratuitous-arps
ip cef
!
!
!
!
!
no ip bootp server
no ip domain lookup
ip domain name example.net
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
ip ssh version 2
ip scp server enable
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 duplex full
 speed 100
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 8.2.156.1 255.255.255.248
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 8.2.156.98 255.255.255.192
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.70
 encapsulation dot1Q 70
 ip address 8.2.156.9 255.255.255.248
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.80
 encapsulation dot1Q 80
 ip address 8.2.156.22 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 8.2.156.18 255.255.255.248
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.210
 encapsulation dot1Q 210
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.301
 encapsulation dot1Q 301
 ip address 8.2.157.129 255.255.255.240
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip mtu 1400
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1360
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
 ip address 77.5.34.106 255.255.255.252
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1300
 duplex full
 speed 100
 media-type sfp
 no cdp enable
 no mop enabled
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
 ip address 77.5.34.106 255.255.255.252
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1300
 duplex full
 speed 100
 media-type sfp
 no cdp enable
 no mop enabled
!
router bgp 64729
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 8.2.156.0 mask 255.255.252.0
 neighbor 77.5.34.105 remote-as 64613
 neighbor 77.5.34.105 filter-list 150 out
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip as-path access-list 150 permit ^$
no ip http server
ip http access-class 80
ip http authentication aaa
ip http secure-server
ip http secure-port 8443
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 77.5.34.105
ip route 8.2.156.0 255.255.252.0 8.2.156.6
ip tacacs source-interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
!

access-list 8 permit 8.2.157.9
access-list 8 permit 8.2.157.10
access-list 8 permit 25.146.194.24
access-list 8 permit 8.2.157.128 0.0.0.15
access-list 8 deny   any log
access-list 80 permit 8.2.157.9
access-list 80 permit 8.2.157.10
access-list 80 permit 8.2.157.25
access-list 80 permit 8.2.156.130
access-list 80 permit 25.144.90.13
access-list 80 permit 25.144.90.12
access-list 80 permit 25.144.90.51
access-list 80 permit 25.144.90.50
access-list 80 permit 25.144.85.32 0.0.0.31
access-list 80 permit 25.144.101.32 0.0.0.31
access-list 80 permit 25.144.92.32 0.0.0.31
access-list 80 permit 25.149.202.128 0.0.0.127
access-list 80 permit 25.144.108.32 0.0.0.31
access-list 80 permit 25.149.181.128 0.0.0.127
access-list 80 deny   any log
access-list 110 permit tcp host 8.2.157.9 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 8.2.157.10 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 8.2.157.25 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 8.2.156.130 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp 8.2.157.128 0.0.0.15 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 25.146.194.24 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp 25.144.85.32 0.0.0.31 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp 25.144.101.32 0.0.0.31 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp 25.144.92.32 0.0.0.31 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp 25.149.202.128 0.0.0.127 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp 25.144.108.32 0.0.0.31 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp 25.149.181.128 0.0.0.127 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 25.144.90.12 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 25.144.90.13 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 25.144.90.50 any eq 22
access-list 110 permit tcp host 25.144.90.51 any eq 22
access-list 110 deny   ip any any log
```

Comment: Please add your configurations to question we can help you. But Guessing will not be a good answer.

Comment: router bgp 65001  
 network 25.141.156.0 mask 255.255.252.0  
 neighbor 25.231.34.105 remote-as 65677  
 neighbor 25.231.34.105 filter-list 150 out

as-path access-list permit ^$

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 25.231.34.105  
ip route 25.141.156.0 255.255.252.0 25.141.156.6 - Note .6 is the switch vlan.

Comment: The configuration you posted does not appear to add any communities.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration doesn’t add any community, you have to use a route-map to do this. For exemple:

```
!
  neighbor GRIF-iBGP-IPv4 route-map SET-iBGP-COMM out
!
route-map SET-iBGP-COMM permit 10
 set community 64496:2150 additive
!
```

This is a peer-group but it’s easily adaptable to a single neighbor.